# How can I fix this ElasticSearch Fielddata exception in Java code?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm working on Java code to create an index and query on ElasticSearch.
I keep getting this exception when trying to use count, sort API:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true ......
```

How can I set Fielddata to true?

I used BulkRequest to create index, how can I add mapping to BulkRequest?

Here is the code to create index:

```
BulkRequest request=new BulkRequest();

    try {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
            request.add(new IndexRequest(indexName, type).source(line, XContentType.JSON)); ;
            BulkResponse bulkresp=client.bulk(request);
            afterBulk(request,bulkresp);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at this doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-create-index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's go to the source of the problem, you want to do a sorting operation on the text field, which requires you to have fielddata enabled.

> Before you enable fielddata, consider why you are using a text field
>   for aggregations, sorting, or in a script. It usually doesn’t make
>   sense to do so.
>
> A text field is analyzed before indexing so that a value like **New York**
>   can be found by searching for **new** or for **york**. A terms aggregation on
>   this field will return a **new** bucket and a **york** bucket, when you
>   probably want a single bucket called **New York**.

Same would be the case for sorting. How you're suppose to sort on the field, where you have tons of terms.

> Instead, you should have a *text* field for full text searches, and an
>   unanalyzed *keyword* field with *doc_values* enabled for aggregations,
>   as follows

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "my_field": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To the other part of the question - you need to take a look at `CreateIndexRequest`, it allows to specify mappings explicitly. Most likely, right now you're using dynamics ones, that's why fielddata causes you the problems. More information on how to use CreateIndexRequest - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-create-index.html#java-rest-high-create-index